# 2 core-plot graphs with different y axes but the same x axis but with different ranges

Tags: core-plot

I've got 2 data sets which both use a date range in the x axis. One had data for the entire date range while the other has data only for the
part of the range. (They use independent y axes on the left and right and that works perfectly.) For example:

1. 131 data points occurring between 1/1/2015 and 5/1/2015
2. 10 data points occurring from 4/15/2015 to 5/1/2015

I want the plots superimposed with the #2 being plotted only in the upper range of dates.

I currently create the data labels for the x axis myself setting the labels based on the 131 data points in #1.

Since #2 only has 10 data points, I need to map it to the 10 positions in the 131 positions on the x axis that correspond to its dates.  I've done this in numberForPlot by using an array that contains a map between the 10 data points of #2 to the correct x axis position of set up by #1.

```
    if ([(NSString *)plot.identifier isEqualToString:@"Pounds"]) {
    switch (fieldEnum) {
        case CPTScatterPlotFieldX:
            return [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:self.xAxisMapping[index]];
            break;

        case CPTScatterPlotFieldY:
        {
            PlotData *pd = (PlotData *)self.plotIDToPlotData[plot.identifier];
            if (pd != nil) {
                NSLog(@"CPTScatterPlotFieldY. index: %lu  returning: %f\n", (unsigned long)index, [pd yValue:index]);
                return([NSNumber numberWithDouble:[pd yValue:index]]);
            }
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
```

There is almost no documentation on CPTScatterPlotFieldX enum but my assumption is that I should take the index parameter based on the number of data points and return the actual position in the x axis. This is exactly what I need and seems like a logical design.

Problem is, it doesn't work; the plot of #2 still expands to fit the entire x axis range.

Can someone help? This must be a common problem where 2 graphs share the x axis but don't have the same number of data points or only partially cover the defined x axis range.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was on the right track with numberForPlot. I fixed the problem by NOT call scaleToFitPlots for #2. This introduced another problem that in spite of setting the y range correctly, the y axis range is much larger than it should be which squishes the plot down to the bottom.

Comment: All fixed. Stupid typo in setting Y range